# Why do these two element locator calls behave differently?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am writing webdriver automation using JavaScript to test a web app.  I have code that looks like this:

```
var selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
By = selenium.By;
until = selenium.until;

driver = new selenium.Builder().
  withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.chrome()).
  build();

getItems = async function() {
  try {
    var itemsXpath = '[xpath expression]';
    var items = await driver.findElements(By.xpath(itemsXpath));
    console.log(items.length + ' items found');
    ...
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This succeeds.  However, if I replace the `await` line with:

```
var items = await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.xpath(itemsXpath)),60000);
```

it does not execute as expected.  Neither the following `console.log()`, nor the one in the `catch()` block, are displayed.

From reading [the documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html), my impression was that if there were items on the page which match the XPath locator, either of these functions would work, and return the elements.  However, if the elements were not on the page, the second formulation would wait for them to appear (up to 60000 ms, in this case).

Note that the second way of writing this does not work, even if the items are already on the screen at the time `getItems()` is called.  Also, the program is completing in less time than the timeout specified in `driver.wait()`.

Is there something I have misunderstood about how this works, such that this behavior actually makes sense?  If so, can anyone clarify what is going on here?

Answer (score -1):

The line you have written:

```
var items = await driver.findElements(By.xpath(itemsXpath));
```

will check for the element and returns `Array<WebElement>` if the given xpath matches with any element(s).

But the wait methods what you used:

```
var items = await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.xpath(itemsXpath)),60000);
```

will not return any element. It simply waits until the element is located in the DOM.

Anyhow, you have specified 60 seconds to find the element using `elementLocated` method. This line will wait a maximum of 60 seconds to find an element matching with your xpath. If the specified xpath matches with any element in less than 60 seconds, it will simply end that wait on that particular time and move to the next line. Note that there won't be any error in such situations. Hence, there is no chance of going to catch block.

You can refer to [this page](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) for more details on this.

Comment: On the page "https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html", in the section for this.wait(), they specifically say that this construct will return the element.  They even give an example of doing something very similar to what I have here.

Comment: The statement what they have written in Returns 'If the input input condition is an instance of a WebElementCondition, the returned value will be a WebElementPromise.' is not correct. You can check java WebDriverWait class and its methods what it does exactly. This class and the methods in this class won't return any element

Comment: The behavior in question, where driver.wait() can return element(s), is one I rely on within my test code, so I know that part works as I expect.  I've never used the Java version of webdriver, so it is possible that version works differently from what I have described.